# PHP is struggling to remove part of JSON string that contains double quotes

Tags: php, arrays, json

Trying to break down the following into an array of dates...

`[["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"14":true}}}],["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"7":true}}}]]`

```
$availableDatesCodeStripped = substr($availableDatesCode, 1, -2);
// Result - ["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"14":true}}}],["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"7":true}}}

$availableDatesCodeArray = explode("],", $availableDatesCodeStripped);
// Array Element 1 Result - ["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"14":true}}}
// Array Element 2 Result - ["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"7":true}}}

foreach($availableDatesCodeArray as $key => $value) {
    $availableDatesCodeArray[$key] = str_replace(":true}}}", " ", $value);
}

// Array Element 1 Result - ["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"14"
// Array Element 2 Result - ["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"7"

foreach($availableDatesCodeArray as $key=>$value){
    $availableDatesCodeArray[$key] = str_replace("[\"custom\",{\"", "", $value);
}

// Array Element Results - NO CHANGE!
```

My aim is to end up with...

`2014-7-14`

`2014-7-7`

So if anyone has a better solution to the way I'm going about it, please say.

Comment: That's not a string,. That's JSON. Work with it appropriately and this is easier to do.

Comment: I agree, @JohnConde, but I would have also added to look into [`json_decode`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: How did you get this JSONObject?

Comment: I basically have a Date Picker on a Wordpress plugin, but I only have the need for one available date per month (if at all), so a drop down would be more practical than a date picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you were to parse it, you would want to tokenize it or use a regex.  This kind of string replacement will just kill you and be wholly unmaintainable.

That being said, your incoming date format is pretty crazy.  It looks like it was designed as a way to store multiple dates in a hash table, but the design is sort of odd.

I got called away, and got beaten to the answer -- but Neil's code won't work.  The issue there is that he's looking at 'custom' as a key, where it is actually a value in the incoming array.  The below is tested against your test data.

```
$availableDatesCode = '[["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"14":true}}}],["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"7":true}}}]]';
$arr = json_decode($availableDatesCode,true);
$dates = array();
foreach ($arr as $dateItem) {
    if ($dateItem[0] == 'custom') // assuming you only want things marked as custom.
    {
        $pDate = array();
        foreach ($dateItem[1] as $year=>$dateMore)
        {
            foreach ($dateMore as $month=>$dateMore2)
            {
                foreach ($dateMore2 as $day=>$ex)
                {
                    $dates[] = implode('-',array($year, $month, $day));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($dates);
```

Comment: I was hoping to see how @user1503689 received this object.

Comment: Although more long winded than Hors Sujet's solution, I'm finding this slightly easier to follow. I've added another date in, formatted the date to display in British format and I'm outputting the dates into a drop down. However, I'm obtaining the data via esc_attr( json_encode( $availability_rules ) ); and with both this solution and Hors Sujet's solution, it breaks when I try and set $availableDatesCode dynamically. I basically have a Date Picker on a Wordpress plugin, but there is only one available date per month (if at all), so a drop down would work better.

Comment: Doh! Finally figured it out... Loose the top two lines and replace the 4th line with... foreach ($availability_rules as $dateItem) {

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered parsing your input correctly?

```
$raw = json_decode($availableDatesCode,true);
$output = array();
foreach($raw as $date) {
    foreach($date[1] as $year => $md) {
        foreach($md as $month => $days) {
            foreach($days as $day => $_) {
                // $_ above because we don't care about the value
                $output[] = sprintf("%04s-%02s-%02s",$year,$month,$day);
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply, but I've got a bit of research to do before I can understand this.

Comment: `foreach($date['custom']` should actually be `foreach($date[1]`

Comment: Will it matter if the day or month isn't 2 digits based on "%04s-%02s-%02s"? When I try and run this I get... array(0) { }

Comment: @user1503689 That "pattern" thingy is to ensure that it *outputs* with 4/2/2 digits, it doesn't matter what the input is. However, I mis-read your input so it wouldn't have worked. Answer has been edited, so update and try now?

Answer (score 0):

Fast solution without json_decode.

```
<?php
$json = '[["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"14":true}}}],["custom",{"2014":{"7":{"7":true}}}]]';
preg_match_all("/([0-9]{4})\W{4}([0-9]{1,2})\W{4}([0-9]{1,2})/", $json, $match);

for ($i = 0;$i < count($match[0]); $i++) {
    echo $match[1][$i]."-".$match[2][$i]."-".$match[3][$i];
}
```

Comment: WOW - Again, this will take me a while to get my head around, if at all, but I really appreciate your help, along with the input from John Green and Niet the Dark Absol

Comment: I'm confused as to how $json when set as a fixed string works perfectly, yet trying to set it using a variable that produces the exact same string, causes it not to work.